# Use of List<T> in C#

Tags: c#

I had to practice making a small program in C#.
I have to enter couple of names, if names.count ==1 then it only shows:

```
"aName Liked post."

if names.count ==2 then:
"aName and bName liked post."

if names.count > 2 then (for example count == 5):

"aName, bName and 3 others liked post."
```

Its working fine with > 2 and ==1 but when there are 2 names i.e. ==2, it throws unhandled exception:

> " **Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Index (zero based)
>   must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the
>   argument list** "

```
var names = new List<string>();

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter name or hit ENTER to quit:");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        break;
    }

    names.Add(input);

}
if (names.Count > 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1} and {2} others liked your post.",names[0], names[1], names.Count-2);
} else if (names.Count == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} liked your post.", names[0], names[1]);
}
else if (names.Count == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} liked your post.", names[0]);
}

else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("No one liked");
}
```

Comment: `"{0} and {2}` Where is 1?

Comment: you could simply lookup String.Format and see why it throws FormatException. Or you could read the error message.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("{0} and {2} liked your post.", names[0], names[1]);

correct: 
Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} liked your post.", names[0], names[1]);

I have been fighting with it for about 30 minutes. Thanks alot for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} and {2} liked your post.", names[0], names[1]);
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} liked your post.", names[0], names[1]);
```

`{2}` is saying "Insert the 3rd parameter into here". But you really want to pass in the second.